# Google Admob banner ads not loading with AnchorType.top

Tags: ios, flutter, banner-ads

I have a Flutter application that I have released on the Android store.   Everything is fully functional, including the banner ads.   I am trying now to get the apple side of the application working, and have been ironing through the myriad apple bugs that stand in the way of this process.

What I am unable to resolve at this point is the banner ads.   They just do not show up at all on the iphone.    I have followed everything in this official guide:  https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/quick-start

I have set  the GADApplicationIdentifier in Info.plist to the app ID of my app from Admob.

I have added GADIsAdManagerApp in Info.plist and set it to YES.

I have added io.flutter.embedded_views_preview in Info.plist and set it to YES.

I have downloaded an up to date, fresh GoogleService-info.plist file from the portal and added it to the runner folder of my app, but even after all these steps I get:

[image: apple error]

And no other information that may give any clues as to the reason for the failure.

My code for the banners (working fine in Android):

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXX');
    _loadBannerState();
    super.initState();
  }

  _loadBannerState() async {
      myBanner
        ..load()
        ..show(
          anchorOffset: 0.0,
          anchorType: AnchorType.top,
        );
    }
  }

  static MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    keywords: <String>['flutterio', 'beautiful apps'],
    contentUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
    childDirected: false,
    designedForFamilies: true,
    gender: MobileAdGender.unknown,
    testDevices: <String>["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"], // Android phone
  );

  BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
    adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX', //Banner_OnePlayer
    size: AdSize.banner,
    targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
    listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
      print("BannerAd event is $event");
    },
  );
```

Has anyone got Admob banner ads working in IOS?

---

#### EDIT:

So I have found the cause of the error but not the solution.   The entire problem is caused by this one line:

```
anchorType: AnchorType.top,
```

With this set, the ad will completely fail to load on IOS.   If I set this to bottom, the ad loads perfectly fine.    Seems like yet another terrible IOS bug but I have no idea how to resolve this, bearing in mind that I need the banner to be displayed at the top of the screen.

Is there another way to achieve this positioning without using anchortype??

Comment: is your banner add id is correct?

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate.   The application ID from Admob is copied and pasted, and verified correct.   It works perfectly in Android, so it must be.

Comment: Cause of issue found, described in edit above.

Comment: Still no solution to this one.  Can't understand why it behaves this way.

Comment: @Bisclavret I never used banner ad, but sounds like you are right there is a bug in iOS, the ad was being displayed above the `AppBar`, I have added a solution how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

If you are using `AnchorType.top` try this:

```
myBanner
  ..load()
  ..show(
    anchorOffset: kToolbarHeight + 50, // 50 is the height of the banner ad
    anchorType: AnchorType.top, // it should work now because we have added offset
);
```

---

If you are using `AnchorType.bottom` try this:

```
myBanner
  ..load()
  ..show(
    // it makes sure we are right below the AppBar, 50 is the height of Banner ad
    anchorOffset: queryData.size.height - kToolbarHeight - 50 - queryData.padding.top - queryData.padding.bottom,
    anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
);
```

---

**Tested on (including both portrait and landscape)**

- iPhone XS simulator
- iPhone 6s real device